# JavaScript throw statement *Help needed*

Tags: javascript, exception, throw

This is part of my H.W. practice and I am stuck on what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated :)

Add a throw statement to the processNumbers function that throws the message "All elements in the list should be numbers." if one of the elements in numberList is not a number. Hint: The function isNaN() returns true if the parameter is not a number.

```
function processNumbers(numberList) { // Code will be tested with different values of numberList
   let result = 0;

   for (let index = 0; index < numberList.length; index++) {
      
      /* Your solution goes here */
      if(isNaN(numberList)){
      throw "All elements in the list should be numbers.";
      }
      /*Solution ends here */
      result += numberList[index] * 1.3 * index;
   }

   return result;
}
```

Comment: I hope those aren't real socials that you are showing online. `VALUE` has to be `VALUES`. You can just do like `INSERT tablename VALUES (column_value1, column_value2, column_value3, ), (column_value1, column_value2, , column_value3);` for multiple inserts in the same query. Your `SELECT` is obviously incorrect. Your `account` table has no `Balance` column *(field)*.  You should `JOIN` another table, not a bunch of results in a subquery. You don't even have a `customer` alias. Just comments.

Comment: yeah this is prewritten and is part of a study guide practice so its just a very basic rough idea

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
select number, type, sum(amount) from (select a.number, a.type, t.amount  from
transaction t inner join account a on a.number = t.account_num inner join 
customer c on c.ssn = a.owner_ssn where c.name = 'Alexander Felix') sub 
group by number, type;
```

Comment: Why do you have a subquery?

Comment: And there's no UNION here

Comment: yup there isn't one but it still works, how would you use a union here?

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
select a.number, a.type, b.Balance, c.name from account as a 
join (select account_num,sum(amount) as Balance from transaction group by account_num) as b on a.number = b.account_num
join (select name, ssn from customer) c on c.ssn = a.owner_ssn
where c.name = 'Alexander Felix';
```

Comment: There's no UNION here

Comment: yup that's true but it still gets the job done. I tried putting a union on between somewhere, but where?

Comment: @CompTech It fails the brief, so no, it doesn't get the job done.

Answer (score -1):

I agree that UNION is entirely unnecessary here, but here's how you might use it:

```
SELECT number
     , type
     , SUM(amount) balance
  FROM 
     ( SELECT a.number
            , a.type 
            , t.amount 
         FROM account a 
         JOIN transaction t 
           ON t.account_num = a.number 
         JOIN customer c 
           ON c.ssn = owner_ssn 
        WHERE c.name = 'Alexander Felix' 
          AND t.type = 'Deposit'
        UNION ALL
       SELECT a.number
            , a.type 
            , t.amount
         FROM account a 
         JOIN transaction t 
           ON t.account_num = a.number 
         JOIN customer c 
           ON c.ssn = owner_ssn 
        WHERE c.name = 'Alexander Felix' 
          AND t.type = 'Withdraw' 
     ) x
 GROUP 
    BY number
     , type;
```

Here's the same thing without a UNION...

```
SELECT a.number
     , a.type 
     , SUM(amount) balance
  FROM account a 
  JOIN transaction t 
    ON t.account_num = a.number 
  JOIN customer c 
    ON c.ssn = owner_ssn 
 WHERE c.name = 'Alexander Felix'
 GROUP
    BY a.number,a.type;
```

Comment: ahhh I see, so, using a union basically overcomplicated things by a lot

Comment: It could almost make sense if 'withdraw' was stored as a positive value, but it isn't, so I really can't see the point- but maybe I'm missing something.